# Defining local variables in scala constructor

Tags: scala

I have a scala class:

```
class Foo {

  def this(st: String) {
      var baz = List[String]()
      var jaz = "one" + st
      // more code logic


  }

}
```

First above code does not compile. Secondly I want baz and jaz to be private variables local to the lone constructor above and not instance variables.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/203968  has a few free Scala books in it read one of them. for instance http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/

Comment: @oluies dude it's like a gold mine!!! thx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not compile because the first thing that MUST happen in an auxiliary constructor is a call to the primary constructor. I don't understand the second question, since the variables you have declared already ARE private

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is maybe what you are looking for?

```
class Foo(st: String) {

  val myInstance = {
      var baz = List[String]()
      var jaz = "one" + st
      jax + baz.mkString(":")
  }
}
```

The body of your class *is* the constructor.  If you want to have some temporary values, you can declare a block with just about anything you want; that block can return a value, and you can store that value in an instance variable, in this case `myInstance`.

Comment: In case you need one value multiple times, you can combine the blocks into one and return a tuple.